# column to be hidden while creating list item but visible while editing the list item in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

for a sharepoint list . i want a column to be not visible when creating new item of the list , but it should be visible when the item is edited .

How can i do this ?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just set ShowInNewForm to FALSE

If you're creating the list using CAML then just add ShowInNewForm="FALSE" to the  element for the field

If you're using the UI to create the field then you can use the object model or [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com) to change the ShowInNewForm property of the field