# How to modify the sharepoint list content type and the view using Web Services

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I posted one question on same site ( [site Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208113/sharepoint-updatelist-method-newly-created-columns-are-not-visible) ) .

Got one solution but i don't know How to modify the sharepoint list content type (which defines new/edit forms) and the view (which defines list views)?